# Sum a string every time new data insert in php

Tags: php, string, sum

I have a variable(database column value) which value is look like below.

**ALI-0001**

now i wanna auto increment this code like **ALI-0002**, **ALI-0003**,**ALI-0004**,**ALI-0005** every time i insert new data.
I tried the following code.

```
$project_code = $a[0]->project_code;
$integer = (integer) substr($max_issue_number, 4);
$sum = $integer+1;
$issue_number = $project_code.'-000'.$sum;
```

Comment: What's the value of `$max_issue_number` and `$a`?

Comment: $project_code = ALI-0001

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is `str_pad` ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php

So your code should be as below:

```
$issue_number = $project_code.'-'.str_pad($sum, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```